# Interface Builder in Xcode 11.6 (11E708) displays storyboards in XML format

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am currently running Xcode version 11.6 and for whatever reason Main.storyboard displays only XML version. I tried to Google around a bit but unfortunately found anything that works. Here's a screenshot:

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idmYX.png)

Any ideas on how to get this to work the way it did before ?

Comment: rightClick on it in left menu -> Open As -> InterfaceBuilder / Storyboard

Comment: Yes, I tried that already but after I try to make connections between my views and header files, Xcode automatically is displaying XML version. Any ideas ?

Comment: I found a solution thanks to this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTn02yqIj6w

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not in version editor mode

[image: Version editor mode]